# HttpContext.Current.User on a Linux, Nginx server and Node JS?

Tags: node.js, .net, ubuntu

I am working on an Enterprise web application for a large company.
The application will be hosted on their internal servers and will be accessed from employees' PCs (Windows 10 only).

Currently, all their internal web applications are written in .NET and they are recognizing users using `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`.

I will be running my application on Ubuntu with Nginx and Node (a very strange beast in a world full of .NET apps).

Will I be able to identify their users using the `HttpContext` also? If not, is there a workaround/different approach?